# Root element ID differed from reactRootID

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Have a react.js component that makes three ajax calls inside of the *componentDidMount* method and sets the state based on the result of each call. The error in the title appeared when I "chained" the calls so that they execute in a specific order. If I execute this without the chaining there is no error however this doesn't work 100% because there is no guarantee that A will complete before B and B will complete before C.

Why is react complaining about Root element ID?

```
componentDidMount() {
    var self = this;

    // this doesn't produce the error but is not acceptable
    $.ajax({.. A ..}).done(function(result) { self.setState({a: result}); });
    $.ajax({.. B ..}).done(function(result) { self.setState({b: result}); });
    $.ajax({.. C ..}).done(function(result) { self.setState({c: result}); });

    // chaining doesn't work
    //self.getA();
    // Root element ID differed from reactRootID
}

getA() {
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({...})
        .done(function(result) { self.setState({a: result}); self.getB(); });
}

getB() {
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({...})
        .done(function(result) { self.setState({b: result}); self.getC(); });
}

getC() {
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({...})
        .done(function(result) { self.setState({c: result}); });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because react doesn't like chaining multiple setState()`s inside a componentDidMount.

Better setup:

- call getA from componentDidMount.
- include gotTo: 'A' in state
- in componentDidUpdate: call getB (if this.state.gotTo == 'A') else call getC